# Does the Mark on Shyvana's Flame Breath proc Spellvamp?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been thinking of creative builds for Shyvana to maximize her magic damage when I thought of using a Hextech Gunblade in the build. If she auto attacks an enemy that is marked with Flame Breath (E), will it apply Spellvamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flame Breath is a pass-through linear skill shot. While in Dragon form, it is a pass-through conic skill shot.

- Applies spell effects as an area of effect ability.
- Hextech Revolver item Spell vamp is reduced to one-third effectiveness.
- Rylai's Crystal Scepter will apply a 15% slow.
- Magic damage will be mitigated by  Black Shield and Lifeline.
- Banshee's Veil item Spell shields will block the ability.

Additional Information:

- **Flame Breath's mark damage will not apply spell effects.**

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shyvana#Flame_Breath